# Spring boot 404 and still works

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When i run my spring boot application as JAR file, all my controllers work fine(though i still get "Did not find handler method for ..." in logs but somehow appropriate controller and view is rendered just fine. When i run this in WAR mode, it's giving me 404 with same error in logs "Did not find handler method for ...".

Here is my application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RAApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    //set register error pagefilter false
    //setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
    return application.sources(RAApplication.class);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(RAApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

My main application class is under com.xyz.abc and all controllers under say com.xyz.abc.controllers and every other component is in child package of com.xyz.abc .

/mappings and /beans work just fine and /mappings do show something like this :

```
"{[/],methods=[GET]}":{"bean":"requestMappingHandlerMapping","method":"public java.lang.String com.xyz.abc.controllers.HomeController.renderIndexPage(org.springframework.ui.Model)"}
```

FYI, I checked there is only one mapping of [/] in case it's useful.

Any pointers to what might be going wrong? All usual searches points to controllers not being found but /mappings show all of them are mapped correctly but why does it give 404 in war mode and works with error in jar mode?

Thanks!

**UPDATE** : I've set

```
servlet.contextPath=/
```

in application.properties and rest other actuator endpoints are configured correctly too e.g.

```
15:21:09.253 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.254 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.254 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.254 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.254 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.255 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.255 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Filter errorPageFilter was not registered (disabled)
15:21:09.255 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean - Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
15:21:09.255 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean - Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
15:21:09.289 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Initializing filter 'requestContextFilter'
15:21:09.291 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
15:21:09.291 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter - Initializing filter 'applicationContextIdFilter'
15:21:09.291 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter - Filter 'applicationContextIdFilter' configured successfully
```

Comment: is your RabbitAssistApplication and controllers in same package?

Comment: Controllers are in child packages of where the Application class is. e.g. com.xyz.abc - application and com.xyz.abc.controllers - controllers

Comment: Are your able to see any logs like below s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public for all your endpoints

Comment: @AmitKBist No i don't and that's why this question.

Comment: Have you marked spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency as provided when creating war from maven?

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your WAR in a web container like Tomcat then you have a context path.

For example localhost:8080/ in JAR mode becomes localhost:8080/myapp/ in web container.

Comment: I've set servlet.contextPath=/ in application.properties. Forgot to mention that, updated the question. Sorry!

Comment: but how do you run the WAR?